# How do I conditionally provide S3 methods for S3 generics from another package?

Tags: r, r-package, r-s3

I'm making a package for data manipulation that uses some other libraries under the hood. Let's say that my data always has a class `"custom"` and that I have a function `custom_select()` to select some columns.

I would like my package to have few dependencies but also a similar syntax as functions from `dplyr`. Because several `dplyr` functions are generics, I can use the same function names for a different input type. In my situation, I could make a method `select.custom()` so that the user can either pass a `data.frame` or a `custom` object to `select()` and both would work.

Now from my understanding, this requires putting `dplyr` in `Imports` because I need to have access to its `select()` generic. I'd like to avoid doing this because I want to limit the number of hard dependencies.

The scenario I have in mind is:

- the user already loads `dplyr` anyway, then they can use `select()` with the data of class `custom` and it should work
- the user doesn't have `dplyr` installed/loaded, and I don't want to force them to have it, so they can use the function `custom_select()` instead.

Ideally, I'd like to put `dplyr` in `Suggests` so that it's not strictly necessary but it adds something if the user has it.

---

##### Example

`custom.R`:

```r
#' @export
#' @importFrom dplyr select
custom_select <- function(data, select) {
  print("Hello, world!")
}

#' @export
select.custom <- custom_select
```

`NAMESPACE`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(custom_select)
export(select.custom)
importFrom(dplyr,select)
```

R CMD check errors if I don't put `dplyr` in `Imports` and putting it in `Suggests` also doesn't work (same error for both cases):

```
❯ checking package dependencies ... ERROR
  Namespace dependency missing from DESCRIPTION Imports/Depends entries: 'dplyr'
```

---

**In summary**, is there a way to keep `dplyr` out of hard dependencies while still providing methods for `dplyr`'s generics if it is available?

---

---

**Edit:** I tried @VonC's answer but couldn't make it work. In the example below, `dplyr` is loaded before my custom package so `select.custom()` should be available but isn't:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(custompackage)

foo <- letters
class(foo) <- "custom"

custom_select(foo)
#> [1] "Hello, world!"
select(foo)
#> Error in UseMethod("select"): no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "custom"
```

Here are the important files:

`custom.R`

```r
#' @export
custom_select <- function(data, select) {
  print("Hello, world!")
}

if (requireNamespace("dplyr", quietly = TRUE)) {
  select.custom <- function(data, select) {
    custom_select(data, select)
  }
  utils::globalVariables("select.custom")
}
```

`NAMESPACE`

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(custom_select)
```

`DESCRIPTION` (no `Imports`)

```
[...]
Suggests:
  dplyr
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to know if the calling environment is aware of your dependency.  The data.table package does that reliably [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/88039186915028ab3c93ccfd8e22c0d1c3534b1a/R/cedta.R), so probably a good place to start...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put **dplyr** in `Enhances` and use `.onLoad` to conditionally register your method in the **dplyr** namespace, depending on whether **dplyr** is installed at *load time*.

```r
nm <- package <- "TestPackage"
dir.create(file.path(package,     "R"), recursive = TRUE)
dir.create(file.path(package,   "man"), recursive = TRUE)
dir.create(file.path(package, "tests"), recursive = TRUE)

cat(file = file.path(package, "DESCRIPTION"), "
Package: TestPackage
Version: 0.0-0
License: GPL (>= 2)
Description: A (one paragraph) description of what
  the package does and why it may be useful.
Title: My First Collection of Functions
Author: First Last [aut, cre]
Maintainer: First Last <First.Last@some.domain.net>
Enhances: dplyr
")

cat(file = file.path(package, "NAMESPACE"), "
export(selectDotZzz)
")

cat(file = file.path(package, "R", paste0(nm, ".R")), "
selectDotZzz <- function(.data, ...) 0
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    if(requireNamespace(\"dplyr\", quietly = TRUE))
        registerS3method(\"select\", \"zzz\", selectDotZzz,
                         envir = asNamespace(\"dplyr\"))
}
")

cat(file = file.path(package, "man", paste0(nm, ".Rd")), "
\\name{whatever}
\\alias{selectDotZzz}
\\title{whatever}
\\description{whatever}
")

cat(file = file.path(package, "tests", paste0(nm, ".R")),
    sprintf("library(%s)", nm))
cat(file = file.path(package, "tests", paste0(nm, ".R")), append = TRUE, "
if(requireNamespace(\"dplyr\", quietly = TRUE))
    stopifnot(identical(dplyr::select(structure(0, class = \"zzz\")), 0))
")

getRversion()
packageVersion("dplyr")
tools:::Rcmd(c("build", package))
tools:::Rcmd(c("check", Sys.glob(paste0(nm, "_*.tar.gz"))))

unlink(Sys.glob(paste0(nm, "*")), recursive = TRUE)
```

The relevant output:

```
> getRversion()
[1] '4.3.1'
```

```
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] '1.1.2'
```

```
> tools:::Rcmd(c("build", package))
* checking for file 'TestPackage/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'TestPackage':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building 'TestPackage_0.0-0.tar.gz'
```

```
> tools:::Rcmd(c("check", Sys.glob(paste0(nm, "_*.tar.gz"))))
* using log directory '/Users/mikael/Desktop/R-experiments/codetools/TestPackage.Rcheck'
* using R version 4.3.1 Patched (2023-06-19 r84580)
* using platform: aarch64-apple-darwin22.5.0 (64-bit)
* R was compiled by
    Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
    GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.2.0
* running under: macOS Ventura 13.4
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file 'TestPackage/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* this is package 'TestPackage' version '0.0-0'
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package 'TestPackage' can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking top-level files ... OK
* checking for left-over files ... OK
* checking index information ... OK
* checking package subdirectories ... OK
* checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... OK
* checking R files for syntax errors ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded ... OK
* checking whether the package can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the package can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be loaded with stated dependencies ... OK
* checking whether the namespace can be unloaded cleanly ... OK
* checking loading without being on the library search path ... OK
* checking startup messages can be suppressed ... OK
* checking dependencies in R code ... OK
* checking S3 generic/method consistency ... OK
* checking replacement functions ... OK
* checking foreign function calls ... OK
* checking R code for possible problems ... OK
* checking Rd files ... OK
* checking Rd metadata ... OK
* checking Rd cross-references ... OK
* checking for missing documentation entries ... OK
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... OK
* checking Rd \usage sections ... OK
* checking Rd contents ... OK
* checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... OK
* checking examples ... NONE
* checking for unstated dependencies in 'tests' ... OK
* checking tests ...
  Running ‘TestPackage.R’
 OK
* checking PDF version of manual ... OK
* DONE

Status: OK
```

Comment: That is more accurate than my answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining your method within an if statement that checks if the package is available, and using `utils::globalVariables()` to avoid R CMD check notes about undefined global functions or variables.

Altering the namespace of another package is generally not allowed [according to CRAN policies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html), and trying to assign a function directly to `dplyr::select.custom` would likely not be acceptable.

The idea is therefore to assign the method to `select.custom` in the global environment, which will allow it to be used as a method for the generic `select()` function if `dplyr` is loaded. The key point is that you are not modifying the `dplyr` namespace directly.

You would need to adjust your `custom.R` file:

```r
#' Custom select function
#'
#' @export
custom_select <- function(data, select) {
  print("Hello, world!")
}

if (requireNamespace("dplyr", quietly = TRUE)) {
  select.custom <- function(data, select) {
    custom_select(data, select)
  }
  utils::globalVariables("select.custom")
}
```

And for the `NAMESPACE` file, you can avoid importing anything from `dplyr`:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(custom_select)
```

In your `DESCRIPTION` file, you should list `dplyr` under `Suggests`:

```
Suggests:
    dplyr
```

This way, if the user has `dplyr` loaded, the `select.custom` method will be available. If `dplyr` is not loaded, the user can still use the `custom_select()` function. This approach keeps `dplyr` out of the hard dependencies while still providing methods for `dplyr`'s generics if it is available.

That will create a function `select.custom` in your package's namespace, which will be used as a method for `select()` when the `dplyr` package is loaded. Note that this does not modify the `dplyr` namespace itself.

Also, it is a good idea to document that the `select.custom` functionality is only available if `dplyr` is installed and loaded, and that `dplyr` is a suggested, not required, dependency.

In your `DESCRIPTION` file, you should list `dplyr` [under `Suggests`](https://r-pkgs.org/description.html#sec-description-imports-suggests):

```
Suggests:
    dplyr
```

This approach should be compliant with CRAN policies, as you are not altering another package's namespace and are conditionally defining methods based on the availability of the `dplyr` package.

---

That being said, [Mikael Jagan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12685768/mikael-jagan) points out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475424/conditionally-provide-methods-for-generics-from-another-package#comment134919489_76497080) to "[Writing R Extensions / Creating R packages / Package structure / Package Dependencies / Suggested packages](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies)"

> **WARNING**: Be extremely careful if you do things which would be run at installation time depending on whether suggested packages are available or not—this includes top-level code in R code files, `.onLoad` functions and the definitions of S4 classes and methods.
>
> The problem is that once a namespace of a suggested package is loaded, references to it may be captured in the installed package (most commonly in S4 methods), but the suggested package may not be available when the installed package is used (which especially for binary packages might be on a different machine).
>
> Even worse, the problems might not be confined to your package, for the namespaces of your suggested packages will also be loaded whenever any package which imports yours is installed and so may be captured there.

Comment: @SamR That would not be allowed indeed. I have rewritten the answer to take that into account.

Comment: Hmm ... I would encourage a careful reading of [Section 1.1.3](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) (including 1.1.3.1) of WRE, notably the warning in bold at the bottom.

Comment: @MikaelJagan That is an important caveat indeed. I have included the warning in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks but I can't make this work (see the edit at the bottom of my post)